# How do I design a microgrid using Simulink?

Tags: simulink, power-grid, microgrid

I have to do a project in which I have to model a microgrid which is controlled by using reinforcement learning techniques.

In doing so I have a problem, because I study control systems and I don't know how to model a microgrid using Simulink or Simscape.

I need to have in my model of the microgrid a solar panel, some buildings and a storage system, but I have no idea how to model them and searching on internet there is not much, and what I find is not clear since it expect to know a lot of concepts I don't know.

Can somebody help me understand how to model such microgrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This video has all the basics you need](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_KjJqj_lBo)

Just remember:
 1. Always drag and drop 'Powergui'. Otherwise, nothing related to electricity will work.
 2. Only drag and drop blocks from a single library. If you use components from multiple libraries, then Simulink can't simulate it.

If you can't find your desired component in the library you are using, then make a transfer function of it and use that.